# Gatsby Build error failed to generate Javascript and CSS bundles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I want to know why I am getting this error trying to build this website through Netlify and Gatsby Cloud. The build works in local development. I have googled to figure out what my issues might be. I have tried deleting my node_modules. My config file has all of the plugins I use. I have been stuck for a few days trying to launch my portfolio project.

[image: Build Error Logs]

This is my SEO component

```
const SEO = ({ description, lang, meta, title })  => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
     {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            keywords
            github
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = site.siteMetadata.description || description 
  const defaultTitle = site.siteMetadata.title;
  const keywords = site.siteMetadata.keywords;

  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={defaultTitle ? `%s | ${defaultTitle}` : null}
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          name: `keywords`,
          content: keywords,
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    />
  )
}
```

This is my Layout Component

```
import React from "react"
import Navbar from "./Navbar"
import Footer from "./Footer"


const Layout = ({ children }) => (
    <>
      <Navbar />
        {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
);
```

Gatsby-Browser and Gatsby-SSR files are both

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./src/components/Layout";
import GlobalStyle from "./src/styles/GlobalStyles";

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
    <>
        <GlobalStyle />
        {element}
    </>
)

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => (
    <Layout {...props}>
        {element}
    </Layout>
)
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated. But is your SEO file somehow not included due to your .gitignore file? Reference: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25992#issuecomment-664951924

Comment: No it's not referenced in the .gitignore file. But good to know to check the gitignore in the future.

Comment: Does the site builds locally?  Do you have a link to the repo?

Comment: Yea it builds locally. This is the link to the repo : https://github.com/nurolkel/portfolio-gatsby